# gcc can't find zlib in mingw installation

Tags: gcc, dll, mingw, zlib, msys

I am trying to install mingw to build a git repo. I am unfamiliar with this type of development and am unable to get gcc to recognize one of the libraries I need (zlib).

So far, I have installed zlib mingw and msys using the mingw installation manager.

[image: mingw install]

The repo is located at C:\zsnes-main and my mingw install is located at C:\MinGW. I have added mingw\bin to my PATH variable. (I also added NASM as the build uses that too).

[image: PATH]

if I run mingw32-make, I get the following error:

[image: mingw32-make]

I also tried moving the repo to C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\user\zsnes-main and running make with the msys shell. I get a similar error.

[image: make]

I am not sure how to resolve this. Clearly it is because gcc does not know how to find zlib, but I don't know how to fix that. It is probably very obvious, but I am new to msys/mingw/gcc so I really have no idea. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I tried using a different distro as suggested, and installed cygwin with pkgconfig etc. The issue is still the same:

[image]

I have tried installing zlib, zlibdevel, zlib0 and mingw64-x86_64-zlib. zlib.h is located in the file directory C:\cygwin\usr\include. It still cannot find the file.

Comment: There are numerous MinGW distributions. The one you're using is not the best one. [Here's a good one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2).

Comment: This specific error is caused by `pkg-config` not being installed. It could be available in your MinGW packages, and it's definitely available in MSYS2 packages.

Comment: *"I tried using a different distro as suggested"* I didn't suggest Cygwin. I suggested MSYS2.